# how is the best option for ibm iseries legacy code consuming web services

Tags: web-services, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Scenario: old legacy code in rpg have to consume data from a new web service 
I think in a new stored procedure implemented in any language to act like a proxy but sure there are better options
Some options i have seen is http://www.rpg-xml.com/ (third party propietary)
or using Java stored procedures with DB2 XML Extender

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are really good options. It really depends on your expertise in your team. If all you know is RPG, use the RPG solution. If you have someone with .NET or Java experience, then use that.

If you have more questions related to this, there is a great community of developers that can help on the [Web400 mailing list](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/web400).